# Select atleast two matching variable within columns in a dataframe and create a new column using r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 3 or more column and I need to extract those item from the column which exist in two or more column in a dataframe and place those item in new column. here is my data for your reference

```
df3 <-data.frame(Gene= c("A", "B", "C","D","E","G"),
             G1=c("GH13_22",  "GH109","GT57", "AA3","-","-"),
             G2=c("GH13_22","- ","GT57","AA3", "GT41","PL"),
             G3=c("GH13", "GH1O9","-", "GT41", "GT41","-"))
```

and output will be like this

```
df3 <-data.frame(Gene= c("A", "B", "C","D","E","G"),
             G1=c("GH13_22",  "GH109","GT57", "AA3","-","-"),
             G2=c("GH13_22","- ","GT57","AA3", "GT41","PL"),
             G3=c("GH13", "GH1O9","-", "GT41", "GT41","-"),
             G4=c("GH13_22", "GH1O9","GT57","AA3","GT41","-"))
```

appreciate your help
I Tried this code could anybody please correct it

```
library(data.table)
Compar <- data.table(df3)
D3<- cazy_Compar[G1==G2|
                 G2==G2|
                 G1==G3]
```

Comment: can you explain the rule more clearly, ie why should `G4[5]` be `"GT41"`?

Comment: sorry some erro was there, i edited

Comment: i still don't understand, the `"GT41"` is only present once in row `E` columns 1-3

Comment: you really need to explain the rule more completely in the question text, eg whe `G4[1]` should be `GH13_22` and not `GT5`

Comment: I edited it as to make it as simple as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it helps to your questions.

```
g4 <- data.frame(G4=rep(NA,6))

for(j in 1:nrow(df3)){
  vec <- c()
  for(i in 2:4){
    a <- df3[j,i]
    vec <- c(vec, a)
  }
  out <- which.max(table(vec))
  g4[j,1] <- names(out)
}

df3[,5]<-g4
```

Comment: Thank you, It helps me learning how to loop, thankyou very much

Comment: I have a big file and it showes error
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 5, value = list(G4 = c("AA", "GT",  : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Comment: @umar can you show me what is the problem exactly ?
Wasn't it run if you change the number (6 in  'g4 <- data.frame(G4=rep(NA,6))' )?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, Its working, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the package `data.table`. If you have never seen this package before the code below could be confusing, so I suggest searching around for some basic resources if you decide to use this solution.

Briefly, `X := Y` creates a new column called `X` using the formula `Y`. The special symbol `.SD` is a placeholder (in this case) the whole dataset, which is then fed into the first argument of `apply()`. Finally, we use the table function to tabulate a given row, and the `which.max()` call then picks the most frequent value in the row.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df3)

df3[, G4 := apply(.SD, 1, \(x) names(which.max(table(x))]
df3
```

Comment: Thank you
Could you please explain this  := and why we use .SD

Comment: @umar I have edited my answer with some explanatory notes.

Comment: Thank you, something new I learned today

Comment: simple way is df$G4 <- apply(df[, 2:4], 1, Mode)